# My d3 Scatter plot is not displaying anything at all

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to get my database code to work, but can't get it to output. Now even trying to output just a varaible with an array of data and it isn't working.

JavaScript File:

```
var w = 600;
var h = 300;

var dataset = [
  [ 5,     20 ],
  [ 480,   90 ],
  [ 250,   50 ],
  [ 100,   33 ],
  [ 330,   95 ],
  [ 410,   12 ],
  [ 475,   44 ],
  [ 25,    67 ],
  [ 85,    21 ],
  [ 220,   88 ]
];


var svg = d3.select("#scatterPlot")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

 svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset) //this will be dataa
    .enter()
    .append("circle")

    .attr("cx", function(d) { //function is getting our data
    return d[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d[1];
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
    return Math.sqrt(h - d[1]);
    });

   .attr("fill", "#00aa88");

  svg.selectAll("text")
     .data(dataset)
     .enter()
     .append("text")
     .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "red");
    .text(function(d) {
    return d[0] + "," + d[1];
     })



  .attr("x", function(d) {
  return d[0];
  })
 .attr("y", function(d) {
 return d[1];
 })




  })();
```

Comment: Check your syntax. For instance you have a `.text(...)` after a line ending with a semi-colon.

Comment: Judging by the last line of your code `})();` I suppose there has to be more JS code, right? What does your HTML look like? What version of D3 are you using? Please try to set up a [mcve] as a Stack Snippet or a JSFiddle.

Comment: You have 2 syntax errors: `.attr('fill',...` after a semi-colon, and `.text(function...` after another. Furthermore, remove `})();``at the end of file for a working sample of your code.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you have some misplace `;`.  Taking these out produces running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="scatterPlot"></div>
  <script>
    var w = 600;
    var h = 300;

    var dataset = [
      [5, 20],
      [480, 90],
      [250, 50],
      [100, 33],
      [330, 95],
      [410, 12],
      [475, 44],
      [25, 67],
      [85, 21],
      [220, 88]
    ];
    
    var svg = d3.select("#scatterPlot")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataset) //this will be dataa
      .enter()
      .append("circle")

    .attr("cx", function(d) { //function is getting our data
        return d[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(h - d[1]);
      })
      .attr("fill", "#00aa88");

    svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d[0] + "," + d[1];
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d[0];
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d[1];
      });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```